# Citus installation failing on GCP

Tags: postgresql, curl

After installing postgresql(13) on GCP, I tried installing citus using this command:

```
curl https://install.citusdata.com/community/rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

However I run into the following error. Any guidance/suggestions would be helpful.

```
[tony_stark@host]$ curl https://install.citusdata.com/community/rpm.sh | sudo bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  8667  100  8667    0     0  21791      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21831
Detected operating system as centos/7.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Checking for postgresql13-server...
Detected postgresql13-server...
Checking for EPEL repositories...
Detected EPEL repoitories
Downloading repository file: https://repos.citusdata.com/community/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=7&source=script... 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 
Network is unreachable
Unable to run: 
    curl https://repos.citusdata.com/community/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=7&source=script
```

The link `curl https://repos.citusdata.com/community/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=7&source=script` works on my browser though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a temporary issue on repository side. I just tried it and it works:

```
[sergiusz@host ~]$ curl https://install.citusdata.com/community/rpm.sh | sudo bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  8667  100  8667    0     0  25686      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25718
Detected operating system as centos/7.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Checking for postgresql13-server...
Installing pgdg13 repo... done.
Checking for EPEL repositories...
Detected EPEL repoitories
Downloading repository file: https://repos.citusdata.com/community/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=7&source=script.
.. done.
Installing pygpgme to verify GPG signatures... done.
Installing yum-utils... done.
Generating yum cache for citusdata_community... done.
The repository is set up! You can now install packages.
```

---

**EDIT:**
This file can be also downloaded manually:
`curl "https://repos.citusdata.com/community/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=7&source=script" -o /etc/yum.repos.d/citusdata_community.repo`

Comment: Nope mate, it still gives the same error for me. And I have no idea if it's because of config or something else.

Comment: Can you download it like this? ```curl "https://repos.citusdata.com/community/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=7&source=script" -o config_file.repo```

Comment: Try ```sudo mv config_file.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/citusdata_community.repo``` and then run ```sudo yum install -y citus102_13``` again.